# Sonar analysis failing with exception after the sonar issues are resolved in the PR

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, bitbucket

We use sonar analysis in our builds triggered from jenkins and the code resides in bitbucket. When the PR is raised and there are no issues reported during the sonar analysis, sonar shows a success on the PR in bitbucket.

However, if the initial run of the PR faces any sonar issue, the sonar analysis repeatedly fails with the below error. This happens even after the code changes are committed to address the sonar issues. Unless we create a new branch and raise the PR again, sonar analysis does not succeed.

Below is the exception seen in the build logs:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project assessment-parent: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor: Unable to perform Bitbucket WS operation: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project assessment-parent:

 - 

    Unable to load component class
       org.sonar.batch.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor     at 

           org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
           Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:65)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:108)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
            ... 19 more
           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.batch.scan.ImmutableProjectReactor
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
            at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
            at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
            at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
            at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1034)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1026)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1003)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
            at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
            at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
            at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.execute(Unknown Source)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:171)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:128)
            at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:63)
            ... 22 more
           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform Bitbucket WS operation
            at com.wirelust.sonar.plugins.bitbucket.PullRequestFacade.init(PullRequestFacade.java:152)
            at com.wirelust.sonar.plugins.bitbucket.PullRequestProjectBuilder.build(PullRequestProjectBuilder.java:51)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectBuildersExecutor.execute(ProjectBuildersExecutor.java:49)
            at org.sonar.batch.scan.ImmutableProjectReactorProvider.provide(ImmutableProjectReactorProvider.java:32)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
            at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
            at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:67)
            ... 56 more
           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.wirelust.sonar.plugins.bitbucket.PullRequestFacade.loadExistingReviewCommentsWithPage(PullRequestFacade.java:229)
            at com.wirelust.sonar.plugins.bitbucket.PullRequestFacade.loadExistingReviewComments(PullRequestFacade.java:216)
            at com.wirelust.sonar.plugins.bitbucket.PullRequestFacade.init(PullRequestFacade.java:148)
            ... 74 more


[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube analysis with Maven' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube analysis with Maven' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Share your configuration

Comment: We are using jenkins 2.99 and sonarqube 5.6. Updated various plugins on jenkins and cleared the jenkins cache.

Comment: This had nothing to do with the jenkins or sonar versions. The issue was in the sonar-bitbucket-integration plugin (https://github.com/teacurran/sonar-bitbucket) where a check for delete flag to be placed before traversing the comments list - looks like bitbucket has done changes in their API implementation which caused failure in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using community version of sonar branch plugin. your sonar.branch.target should be master.

The plugin doesn't currently do any logic around checking branch names, so specifying either sonar.branch.name or source.branch.target would result in an error if the project doesn't already exist.

It would be possible to check whether sonar.branch.name equals master and return a DefaultBranchConfiguration instance in that case, providing sonar.branch.target also equals master - or is blank or unspecified - otherwise there are likely to be problems using the branch at a later point.

I don't know how the official version does this so can't tell if we're being consistent, but the documentation seems to indicate the default branch is created as master so this approach should be consistent.

We'd therefore handle combinations of inputs on a 'missing' project in the following way:

[image: input combinations table]

For more details you can check this link https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin/issues/1